# How do i hide all comments from logged out users

Tags: comments

Is there a way to remove published comments so they're hidden for logged out users?

Comment: You can wrap the comment display code in is_user_logged_in() function. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend looking for all occurrences of `comments_template` in your theme and wrapping them in a `is_user_logged_in` condiational.

Example:

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    comments_template();
}
```

Alternatively, you can open up your theme's `comments.php` (or the equivalent, it's usually `comments.php`) and add something like this at the very top:

```
<?php
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    return;
}
```

PHP let's you return out of files early, so you can "bail" from an include like the above. If you need to remove comments on ALL post types for non-logged in users, the second option is likely the best. If you need it conditionally on some post types, the first is the best.

The best solution, however, is to use your own filters. Rather than calling `is_user_logged_in` directly, call `apply_filters` with a unique name and return try by default.

```
<?php
// somewhere before all the other stuff in comments.php
if (!apply_filters('wpse96406_show_comments', true)) {
    return;
}
```

Then in `functions.php`, hook into your own filter and modify how it behaves.

```
<?php
add_filter('wpse96406_show_comments', 'is_user_logged_in');
```

Why do this? Much more flexible.

Want to show comments on certain posts? The first two options above don't let you do that (without some refactoring). Using your own filter makes things much more extensible for your future self -- or for end users if you're releasing the theme.

Answer (score 1):

Based on an [older article](http://wpengineer.com/2302/how-to-disable-comments-for-wordpress-pages-in-any-theme/), this is how I would do it:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/* Plugin Name: Show comments after login */

if ( ! function_exists( 'wpse_96406_comments_after_login' ) )
{
    add_filter( 'comments_template', 'wpse_96406_comments_after_login', 11 );

    function wpse_96406_comments_after_login( $comments_template )
    {
        return is_user_logged_in() ? $comments_template : __FILE__;
    }
}
```

*Note:* This must be a stand-alone plugin; do not put this code into a theme.

But you can also search for all occurrences of `comments_template()` in your theme and wrap those into a conditional.

Comment: Just a note: if you do this, the above should be the only thing in a file. `comments_template` will just blindly `require` it -- probably don't want anything else going on there.

Comment: @chrisguitarguy I added a warning. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I resolved this by writing the custom function myself based on removing the comments form from Genesis.

Comment: Please use just **one** account.